# Clueless Crossword, then Connect-Wall

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords, connect-wall

**Solve the following crossword that lacks most of the clues (but has some letters revealed), and then perform [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) to the resulting words.**

Please note that this is an [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) – One particular line of thought will instantly solve this puzzle!

[image: The crossword]

**Across:**

- **A.** A misspelt letter. (4)
- **B.** (5)
- **E.** A nymph. (4)
- **F.** (6)
- **G.** (4)
- **H.** (6)
- **J.** A feminine name. (7)
- **L.** (4)
- **O.** (4)

**Down:**

- **C.** (7)
- **D.** (4)
- **I.** (4)
- **K.** (6)
- **M.** A masculine name. (4)
- **N.** (6)
- **P.** (6)

Comment: I assume the missing bits of drop-shadow at the bottom right corner aren't meant to have significance?

Comment: I'm getting a conflict between N and H, or between H and C, depending on what I use for H. Everything else works well enough that it seems unlikely I'm completely on the wrong track. I expect the error is mine none the less, but would be glad if you'd double-check...

Comment: (Duh, it would appear that the error was in fact mine. Not very surprisingly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid:

> ```
>                 D
>                 o
>           N     x
>           A l f a
>           g
>           o   C
>           y   h
>     H a g a k i
>               d
>       F y o d o r   P
>               r     E c h o
>         J u l i e t t
>                     r     K
>                     O l g a
>             B o r I s     w   M
>                   v     G a l i
>                 L a m a   s   k
>                   n       e   e
> ```

The groups:

> Letters from the NATO phonetic alphabet: ALFA, ECHO, JULIETT, MIKE. (These are the ones for which definitions were provided.)

> Letters from the Greek spelling alphabet, transliterated into Latin characters: DOXA, GALI, LAMA, PETROS.

> Letters from the Russian spelling alphabet, transliterated into Latin characters: BORIS, FYODOR, IVAN, OLGA.

> Letters from the Japanese radiotelephony alphabet, transliterated into Latin characters: CHIDORI, HAGAKI, KAWASE, NAGOYA.

Comment: Ha! I had the same idea (and quickly filled in D, N and O), but got stuck after that. My scope is rather limited, apparently.

Comment: rot13(Vg'f abg UNTNXR; vg'f UNTNXV.)

Comment: Oh, apparently I can't read. That would indeed seem to resolve everything.